# Prove that $x^3+y^3+z^3 + 5xyz \ge 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Let $x,y,z \gt 0 \quad$ such that $$x+y+z+2xyz=1+xy+yz+zx$$ Prove that
$$ x^3+y^3+z^3 + 5xyz \ge1 $$

My try (**Proof**).

1) if any of $\{ x,y,z\} \ge 1$, then inequality is obvious.

2)  Assume $\{ x,y,z\} \in (0,1)$, 
$$x+y+z+2xyz=1+xy+yz+zx \quad (*), \quad \Longrightarrow xyz=(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$$

So, we let $x=\frac{a}{a+b}, y=\frac{b}{b+c},z=\frac{c}{c+a}$

and let $u=x+y+z, v=xyz $, from **(*)** we have: $xy+yz+zx=u+2v-1$
$$ x^3+y^3+z^3 + 5xyz \ge1 $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx) +8xyz \ge 1$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (x+y+z)[(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+zx)] +8xyz \ge 1$$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow u[(u^2-3(u+2v-1)] + 8v \ge 1$$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow u^3-3u^2 -3(2v-1)u + 8v-1 \ge 0$$

but $$v=xyz=\frac{abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\le\frac{1}{8}$$
$$u=x+y+z=\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a} \le ?$$

then, i do not know how to continue...

Comment: Wangwang, you've been around for a bit, so please review [ask] and add some context to your problem statement.  Why is this inequality interesting to you?  Where did you find it? Etc.

Comment: I think $(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)+8xyz = u(u^2-3(u+2v-1)) +  8v = u^3-3u^2+3u-6uv+8v$

Comment: @GAVD thanks, I already correct it.

Answer (score -1):

If $x>1$ then our inequality is obvious.

Thus, we can assume that $\{x,y,z\}\subset(0,1]$.

Let $x^3+y^3+z^3+5xyz<1$, $x=ka$, $y=b$ and $z=c$ such that $k>0$ and $$a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc=1.$$

Thus, $$ka^3+b^3+c^3+5kabc<a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc,$$ which gives $0<k<1$.

But, $$1=x+y+z+2xyz-xy-xz-yz=ka+b+c+2kabc-kab-kac-bc=$$
$$=ka(1-b-c+2bc)+b+c-bc=$$
$$=ka((1-b)(1-c)+bc)+b+c-bc<a((1-b)(1-c)+bc)+b+c-bc,$$
which is a contradiction because we'll prove now that
$$1\geq a((1-b)(1-c)+bc)+b+c-bc$$ or
$$1\geq a+b+c+2abc-ab-ac-bc$$ or
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\geq$$
$$\geq(a+b+c)\sqrt[3]{(a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc)^2}-(ab+ac+bc)\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc}$$ or since 
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)$$ and
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\neq-(a+b+c)\sqrt[3]{(a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc)^2},$$ we need to prove that
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc)^3-(a+b+c)^3(a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc)^2+$$
$$+(ab+ac+bc)^3(a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc)+$$
$$+3(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc)(a^3+b^3+c^3+5abc)(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc),$$
which is true by $uvw$.

Indeed, the last inequality is equivalent to
$$(27u^3-27uv^2+6w^3)^3-27u^3(27u^3-27uv^2+8w^3)^2+$$
$$+27v^6(27u^3-27uv^2+8w^3)+27uv^2(27u^3-27uv^2+6w^3)(27u^3-27uv^2+8w^3)$$ or $f(u)\geq0$, where
$$f(u)=27u^3v^6-27uv^8+54u^6w^3-162u^4v^2w^3+108u^2v^4w^3+8v^6w^3+$$
$$+44u^3w^6-60uv^2w^6+8w^9.$$
Easy to see that $f'(u)\geq0$, which says that $f$ increases.

Hence, $f$ gets a minimal for a minimal value of $u$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $b=c=1$, which gives
$$(a-1)^2(2a^5+12a^3+6a^2+5a+2)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: I think it should be $k^3(\sum a^3+5abc)<\sum a^3+5abc=1 \implies 0<k<1.$

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed something. $x=ka$. I upvoted for your nice try.